# Algorithm in C# and Java (Android) into HTML

Tags: java, c#, html, algorithm

I have an algorithm in two languages, C# and java, but I need it in a webpage HTML, witch is the best way to make it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways of doing that. The algorithm can either be executed on client side or on server side.

If you want to do it on the client side you could do it with JavaScript (or less preferable due to massive security issues, Flash)

There are several options for server side solutions such as ASP .NET, PHP, JSP, Node.js (JavaScript on Server), Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Both way are possible. Depends in what environment you want to run your application. If your algorithm doesn't need any back-end specific operations you can also rewrite it into `JavaScript` which you can access very easily from `html` code.